# DOMDocument getNodeValue() returns null (contains an output escaped string)

Tags: java, xml, dom, escaping

I am processing a DomDocument which is basically the XML result of a SOAP web service. 
To give you an idea, this is what it looks like

```
...<ParentNode><ChildNode>&lt;output&gt;&lt;escaped&lt;string</ChildNode></ParentNode>...
```

Yes, the value of ChildNode is a string that has been output escaped and is XML that is packed within this XML. I do the usual run of DomDocument processing such as

```
NodeList rows = dom.getElementsByTagName(ChildNode);
for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{
  System.out.println(rows[i].getParentNode()); // returns ParentNode
  System.out.println(rows[i].getNodeName()); // returns ChildNode
  System.out.println(rows[i].getNodeValue()); // returns null
}
```

After you inspect the above code, you realize that even though the node returns correct values for ParentNode and the NodeName node, it returns a null value upon accessing getNodeValue(). There is a string here, and I can see it in my console output. But I am not sure what trick I am missing here, does the output escaping mess it up in any particular way?

Thanks,
Parijat

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You want `getTextContent()` rather than `getNodeValue()` - the latter always returns null for element nodes.

Comment: I used this in the meantime rows[i].getChildNodes().rows[i].getNodeValue(); and it worked...i wonder why though

Comment: Because the child nodes under the `<ChildNode>` element are _text nodes_, whose node value is the text they contain, as opposed to element nodes, whose node value is always null.

Comment: The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node

Comment: @Ian Robers, How to use getTextContent when text of a node contains html tags like <br>, <br/> etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
rows[i].getNodeValue()
```

use

```
rows[i].getNodeValue().getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()
```