# parsing xml document java with documentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, xmldocument

I have the following in my xml file  and basically I am trying to change an attribute of the xml document

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <root level="DEBUG">
  </root>
</configuration>
```

This is my java file

```
    public static void changeXMLLogLevel(String pathToXMLDocument, String newWarnLevel){
    // make sure that xml file is present
    File f = new File(pathToXMLDocument);

    if (f.exists()) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(pathToXMLDocument);


            // Get the warn level
            Node warnLevel = doc.getElementsByTagName("root").item(0);

            System.out.println("The warn level is: " + warnLevel);

           // more code..................
```

For some reason the warn level is null although I have a tag in my xml document called root.

This is what I get for my output
`The warn level is: [root: null]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand your output. With this

```
Node warnLevel = doc.getElementsByTagName("root").item(0);
```

you get the single `root` tag in your xml. The `toString()` of that object is the name of the tag and the node's value, but apparently [it always returns `null` for element nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413450/domdocument-getnodevalue-returns-null-contains-an-output-escaped-string).

What you want is to get the attribute `level`.

```
Node warnLevel = doc.getElementsByTagName("root").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("level");
System.out.println("The warn level is: " + warnLevel);
```

which prints

```
level="DEBUG"
```