# XPath read root element returns null

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Given an XML file like:

```
<source>
   <element value="a">
   <element value="b">
</source>
```

I'm trying to read the root element ("source") of the XML using Java and XPath:

```
public String parseExpression(Document doc)  {
   NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/").evaluate(
                    doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
   return nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}
```

However it returns null. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOMDocument getNodeValue() returns null (contains an output escaped string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413450/domdocument-getnodevalue-returns-null-contains-an-output-escaped-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.getNodeValue();` does not return the value of the attribute. Try `(Element)nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild()).getAttribute("value")` instead.
The value you are trying to read is not in the element node you are accessing.
It is in a seperate attribute node which is only accessable when you cast your NodeList entry to Element.