# Reading one specific element in a xml payload

Tags: java, xml, dom, payload, nodelist

I'm trying to read information from a specific element, here is my xml payload :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tns:createTicket xmlns:tns="">
<contact>
    <gender>F</gender>
    <firstname>ANNE</firstname>
    <lastname>MP</lastname>
    <phone>88</phone>
  </contact>
  <issue>
    <occurrenceDate>2020-03-23T00:01:00+01:00</occurrenceDate>
    <location>
      <streetName1>Rpp</streetName1>
      <zipCode>999999</zipCode>
      <city>AMMM</city>
      <countryCode>FR</countryCode>
    </location>
    <typeCode>GAM</typeCode>

    <otherInformations>
      <name>Ser</name>
      <value>Two</value>
    </otherInformations>

    <otherInformations>
      <name>deliveryAddress</name>
      <value>RURU</value>
    </otherInformations>

    **<otherInformations>
      <name>**serDat**</name>
      <value>**2020-03-23**</value>
    </otherInformations>**

    <otherInformations>
      <name>gracias</name>
      <value>False</value>
    </otherInformations>
  </issue>
</tns:createTicket>
```

How can I read the informations from this specific element from the payload :

> serDat
>         2020-03-23

I use the Dom librairy in my code but I'm only able to read the informations from the first 'otherinformations' element and not the other one. I don't have this problem when I want to read the informations from an unique element in the XML payload.
EDIT: I've tried the xPath Librairy

```
var factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    var builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder()
    var document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(payload)));
    //var rootElement = document.getDocumentElement()
    var xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance()
    var xpath = xpf.newXPath()
    print(payload)
    var nodes = xpath.evaluate("/createTicketRequest/payload/issue/otherInformations", document, XPathConstants.NODESET) as NodeList
    for(i in 0..nodes.getLength()) {
      print(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }
```

But the result of print(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); is NULL

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please show your code.  Why can't you parse with xpath?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DOMDocument getNodeValue() returns null (contains an output escaped string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413450/domdocument-getnodevalue-returns-null-contains-an-output-escaped-string) Checkout the javadoc of getNodeValue, it is defined to return null on nodes of type "element" (you are probably looking for nodes of type text, but the nodelist you target with your xpath matches the elements, and not their text content).